# How to publish a java project source files on GIT?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, organization

I want to start moving some of my projects onto github repos. I'm a little overwhelmed on how to organize the files on these repos. I want to make sure I do this right. The specific project I've been working on is a Java project I've been building in Eclipse. It is essentially an 'engine' of sorts, so the ideal outcome would be that people clone the repository and build onto it as their own project that uses the engine.

Here is my local project structure.

```
src
--com
----myName
------projectName
test
--com
----myName
------projectName
bin
config.properties
README.md
.gitignore
.classpath
.project
```

One of the first things I did was gitignore everything in the bin folder and all class files.

This doesn't really feel like the 'right' way of doing things. I'm just making guesses. Are there any standard conventions I can adhere to?

Also let me ask some specific questions

1. Is it okay that the java packages are creating many (seemingly redundant) subfolders?
2. Is it correct to ignore the bin folder? Or will that complicate the project if someone else was to clone it?
3. I want to say that the classpath and project folder should also be ignored, but they do reflect changes in files. Am I right in thinking that these should be commitable files?
4. Do I need to make any special changes in organization to reflect how this particular project is an 'engine' that I intended people to clone and use in their own projects?

I feel this is a simple concept I may be over complicating but I want to make sure this is done correctly the first time. Any resources that anyone can point me to regarding git repo organization would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have suggested a change on your tittle in order to avoid confusion with Generics in Java code.

Answer (score 0):

To what my understanding of things, you can do two things :

Share your sources as a Java Library wrapped in a jar file. You can avoid all this "how do i share" questions.

Or you can share the project in a software version tool, like GIT. Ideally you will have to provide to the clients two things : The code and a way to easily setup their environment for coding.

**In your case**

To share the code: The code is under your java source is under src and tests folders.

To allow other persons to setup quickly their environment for working : Let's see, you are using the build system that employs Eclipse, so you should study how to share a eclipse project from a machine from other. What i can tell you in advance is... i thing the bin folder is not necessary (2). But the .classpath and .project it is. That is necessary in order to open the project within the eclipse IDE... the problem is that your IDE perhaps has some particular library or classpath configuration that other Eclipse don't and problems may arise (3).

What i recommend is to share your project using an independent-ide builder. Like maven, for example. Yes.. you always depends on something.. is only a question of what is more easier, and mankind has prove that with things like maven it is more easy.

About question (1), is not bad as long it has sense.

and (4) I think not.